# Email Server on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ec2, postfix-mta

We have an email server running postfix on AWS m1.medium instance. We push out roughly 150,000 emails a week (30,000 emails a day). We do not want to use Amazon SES for some business reasons. It usually takes more than 2 hours for each day's send and we want to reduce this. What suggestions do you have in terms of increasing the AWS instance type / class? There is a number of instance classes and we cannot figure out which class / type would be ideal for our situation. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For your use case, instance size probably does not matter. 30,000 emails over a two hour period is not a lot either of terms of CPU, disk or network requirements.

Most likely you will see improvements by better overlapping of email send requests. This can be accomplished thru software design improvements, or simply splitting your sends via multiple EC2 instances.

Of course I am making a lot of assumptions here as you did not provide any statistics on what you are sending, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify any specifics, I presume that this is some kind of customer relationship thing (newsletter, etc), which will send lots of similar, or even identical emails (bulk emailing).

The problem you're inevitable going to run with in is, your mails getting classified / treated as unsolicited. The symptom you describe as

> It usually takes more than 2 hours for each day's send and we want to reduce this.

Sounds a lot like [greylisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greylisting) and/or [tarpitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) to me. If this is actually the issue, then except making your bulk email look less like spam and your mail delivery system behave like a dumb mass mailer there's little you can do about it.

See also this Q&A: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/19170

Comment: Hi Datenwolf, Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, it is used to send newsletters but it is not unsolicited emails though. All the subscribers have consented to receive that info by subscribing via our website. Further, if it was due to greylisting or tarpitting, would not I see a long mail queue on the server? Usually, the mail queue stays around 80 emails all the time and compared to the size of the send of 30,000, I believe this is pretty good.